# convert all chars in string to hex and put in array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, hex

I have a string `unsigned char msg[] = "abcd";` and would like to convert it to hex and put it in an array to become like this: `char msg_hex[4] = {0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64};` .

How can I do it in C?

Comment: Your question is based on your confusing values with their representations. `int j = 3;` and `int j = 0x3;` both give `j` the same value, three. They just use different representations IN THE SOURCE CODE to do it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Hu, assigning an array?

Comment: I got the question wrong...sorry folks

Comment: @DavidSchwartz.: That's why I first got a bit puzzled...I was so sure that OP would ask for representation....andit turns out this.

Comment: Try: `for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) { printf("msg[%d] = 0x%hhx ('%c')\n", i, msg[i], msg[i]); };`

Comment: @alk Not an array, of course, make `msg_hex` a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is based on a misunderstanding. Values are how much or how many of something you can have. You can have three cars. Representations are ways of encoding values. If you have three cars, you can represent that value as "3" or "III" or "three" and it's the same value. Hex is a means of *representation*.

So consider these two bits of code:

```
int i = 3;

int i = 0x3;
```

They both set `i` to precisely the same value. They just use different representations in the source code. But `i` holds an integer *value* and the implementation uses some internal representation (typically two's complement binary) internally and that internal representation will be the same either way.

So your question doesn't make sense. You can only store values in an array and the implementation always represents them whatever way it needs to represent those particular values.